# What contract is AggregatorV3Interface using?

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.8.x, interfaces

I understand that you combine an interface (which puts function names and parameter/return types in scope) and a deployed contract address which actually implements these functions. My question is, why do all the addresses used with [AggregatorV3Interface](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/develop/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol) have multiple contracts stored at them? First of all, I thought that a single address can only contain one contract. Yet when I look at [the etherscan](https://etherscan.io/address/0x72AFAECF99C9d9C8215fF44C77B94B99C28741e8#code) for the 1INCH/USD price feed, I see multiple contracts. How can this be? Second, how do I know which contract the interface is implementing when there are multiple contracts? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

actually only one main contract `AggregatorProxy` which implement `AggregatorV3Interface` in link you post, others are just libs linked or contracts inherited/imported